# Android Studio is unable to resolve dependency for :app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I installed android studio and `sdk` successfully. but when I created a new project and android studio downloaded `gradle` files for the project and gives me these errors:

> Error: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>
> Error: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version
>   that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. Show Details
>   Affected Modules: app
>
> Error: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that
>   matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+. Show Details Affected
>   Modules: app

I have sync and installed `gradle` many times, but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share your build.gradle file ? Although I am not sure but it may works

Solution 1: Go to "File".
Click on Invalidate Cache/ Restart.
Again click on Invalidate Cache / Restart

Solution 2:  Change

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
to
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update your android studio.
the latest android studio version is 3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

please check your build.gralde. Have it add the `google()` in repositories?